# Use loop variable as portion of field variable name

Tags: c#

I have defined the 8 different C# integer types here:

```
// Eight C# predefined integer types:
sbyte i1 = -128;
short i2 = -32768;
int i3 = -2147483648;
long i4 = -9223372036854775808;
byte i5 = 255;
ushort i6 = 65535;
uint i7 = 4294967295;
ulong i8 = 18446744073709551615;
```

I was able to print them manually like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("i1 has a type of: {0}", i1.GetType());
Console.WriteLine("i2 has a type of: {0}", i2.GetType());
Console.WriteLine("i3 has a type of: {0}", i3.GetType());
Console.WriteLine("i4 has a type of: {0}", i4.GetType());
Console.WriteLine("i5 has a type of: {0}", i5.GetType());
Console.WriteLine("i6 has a type of: {0}", i6.GetType());
Console.WriteLine("i7 has a type of: {0}", i7.GetType());
Console.WriteLine("i8 has a type of: {0}", i8.GetType());
```

However, I would prefer to loop over them and print their types:

```
// print types
for (int j = 1; j < 9; j++){
Console.WriteLine("i{0} has a type of: {1}", j, XXX.GetType());
}
```

What is the best way to combine i and j as a variable name so that I can get it's type?

Comment: Create a List<object> and them to the list.

Comment: Are the objects you defined on the same class?

Answer (score 1):

```
List<object> l = new List<object>();
l.Add(i1);
l.Add(i2);
// and so on...

int j=0;
foreach(var xxx in l)
{
   Console.WriteLine("i{0} has a type of: {1}", j,xxx.GetType());
   j++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop you need an enumerator such as provided when an object implements `IEnumerable`. So what you can do is adding all those types into a List. This code example uses a dictionary and stores the minimum values of the particular types.

```
// declare and define
IDictionary<Type, object> integers = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
integers.Add(typeof(sbyte), sbyte.MinValue);
integers.Add(typeof(short), short.MinValue);
// etc.

// display
int counter = 0;
foreach (KeyValuePair<Type, object> integer in integers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "i{0} has a type of {1} with a minimum value of {2}.",
        ++counter,
        integer.Key,
        integer.Value);
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a dictionary?  Wouldn't `[value].GetType()` be equal to the `[key]`?

Comment: See example. The example doesn't uses instances of i1, i2, etc. and stores the minimum values as shown in the question.

Comment: I don't understand.  Is there an offsite example you are consulting?  I see no mention of "minimum value" by the OP.

Comment: He assigned limit values in his example such as -128 for for an sbyte. The dictionary holds those values depending on the data type. Alternatively just use a list that holds the variables in it.